# Take Textbox input and move to a specific cell.

Tags: vba, excel, textbox

I'm writing a macro to pull various data from an Excel sheet and put it in a more usable order. A problem I've run into is that one section of the data I want is contained in a textbox. I'd like to pull the data out of the textbox and have it all pasted into a cell, `A100`.

The textbox is always called `ActivityA`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
Cells(100, 1) = ActiveSheet.Shapes("NameOfYourTextBox").DrawingObject.Text
```

Comment: so a small follow on question. I've got many different worksheets (tabs) within this workbook and would like this macro to run on all. Typically i can execute this with my simple macros by just ctrl clicking all the different tabs i'd like to run the macro on and then running the macro. In this case that isn't working. Is it something with the activesheet code? Any suggestions on how to make it so this will work on different worksheets when i ctrl click to run the macro?

Comment: @jason: probably best to ask something like this as a separate question... That said, ActiveSheet is just that, the worksheet that has the focus, irrespective of how many worksheets are selected, of even how many workbooks are open.  You can refer to workbooks, worksheets, ranges, shapes etc in many ways other that Active*.  Try Dim sh as WorkSheet For each sh in ActiveWorkbook.Sheets  Cells(blah) = sh.Shapes(blah)... Next sh

Comment: Thank you! I have been searching to a solution to this for a while :)